# How do I get Wit.ai to do math calculations on roles?

Tags: wit.ai

I am new to Wit.ai and I am wondering if the chat bot can do a calculation based off two wit/number:values and then relay the value back to the user.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wit doesn't perform any action/computation. You will have to do it on your code based on the returned entities.